# How to add loading text

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code currently i am load query page and show message in my div.

in my query page in query success then print success

my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {


          var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
        $("#success-result").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

My Div

```
<div class="box-header">
    <h4 id="success-result" class="box-title">Welcome to update page</h4>
</div>
```

I want when drag row then show wait for update process

then when query page print success then show update success

otherwise Welcome to update page

How?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      start: function(){
          $("#success-result").html("loading....");
      },
      update : function () { 

          var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
        $("#success-result").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```